# Unetstack C API with Unetsim simulator

Tags: unetstack

I am trying to run the C API for Unetstack. I have been trying to run the test code [here](https://github.com/org-arl/unet-contrib/blob/master/contrib/Unet-C-API/test_unet.c).

I am running *3-node-network.groovy* from the unetsim-1.4 sample code in my terminal to use as my modem network. I am using unetsim-1.4a for linux for my simulator.

This is how I call the test code:

```
make IP="127.0.0.1" ADDR=1 test
```

The test code is able to open the modem, but is not able to send packets through.
This is the error I end up getting:

```
Packet transmission: FAILED
Packet transmission: FAILED

Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

and I do not see any received packets on my simulator shell.

When I run the *3-node-network.groovy* simulation with the Python API, everything works fine, and I can see packets being received on my simulator shell.

How should I set up the environment to run the Unetstack C API test code to transmit and receive through a simulated modem network on unetsim?

Answer (score 2):

Follow the steps below to set up the environment to test basic modem operations using UnetStack C API with simulated modem network on `unetsim` :

1. Run `3-node-network.groovy` from unetsim-1.4 sample code which creates a simulation environment with 3 nodes deployed as shown below for example:

   `bin/unet samples/rt/3-node-network.groovy`
2. Change the port number from `1100` to `1101` at this [line](https://github.com/org-arl/unet-contrib/blob/master/contrib/Examples/c/examples.c#L47) in the code in your `unet-contrib` local repository.
3. Set the destination address to `2` at this [line](https://github.com/org-arl/unet-contrib/blob/master/contrib/Examples/c/examples.c#L36).
4. Set the carrier frequency to `25000 Hz` at this [line](https://github.com/org-arl/unet-contrib/blob/master/contrib/Examples/c/examples.c#L10).
5. Navigate to this [folder](https://github.com/org-arl/unet-contrib/tree/master/contrib/Examples) in your `unet-contrib` local repository and perform the following steps:

   `make c
   c/examples localhost`

You should be able to see successful transmissions from `node 1` and corresponding receptions on `node 2`.